# Preprocessor directive "being consumed" building dll

Tags: c#, dll, build, c-preprocessor

I have a class with several utility functions. This class is compiled as a dll which is then used in an user editor, of which there are 3 operative versions.

These three versions (let's call them A, B and C) use a core library which is slightly different across the three versions, but named identically as a file, and with overlapping functions and classes.

To compile my dll and be able to interface with the editor I chose one version of the core library, and referenced it in my solution.
For convenience in terms of cross compatibility with the other versions, I choose the B version of the core library.

Now the problem I'm facing: some of the functions / class properties in the core libraries are missing in one version in respect to the others, but I need to be able to address these functions and classes and 'decide' (at runtime?) which property to use, to address the version-specific property of the class / function that the user is running.
Each version of the editor exposes a global define with its version.

```
Simple example:
Version A Class_A
property_1
property_2

Version B Class_A identical to version A

Version C Class_A
property_1
property_3 <= property 2 has disappeared, I must use this as per new api specifications
```

I've tried to use the defines, but I realize that these are 'consumed' when I build, and since I reference the B version of the editor, my DLL is 'baptized' as if the user editor was B, regardless of which editor will later use the DLL.

```
Simple example:
... //some code in my library
public void UseClassA() {
    Class_A newclassA = new Class_A();
    newclassA.property_1 = "x";
    #if VERSION_A || VERSION_B
    newclassA.property_2 = "y";
    #endif

    #if VERSION_C
    newclassA.property_3 = "y";
    #endif
}
^^^ Version C users will get an error when calling this function, since my dll is built with reference to VERSION_B's core dll.
```

As an alternative, I've used reflection, but it feels dirty since I'm forced to do a 'property check' at runtime, instead of a 'version check'.

So the question is, is it possible to maintain the directives in place in my code, so that they're considered at runtime rather than during build? I kind of understand this is not how directives work, so I hope there's an alternative or a way to achieve the desired result.

Comment: This seems like a bad design as far as compatibility goes, strictly from the fact that "X.dll" is not always the same "X.dll." That being said, if your library could specify some sort of revision identifier `#if VERSION_A return 0x01; #endif` or similar, for each version through a common property (or dare I say it - field), then you could easily use that to determine which API to utilize. Addendum: this mandates editing of the source code of the core library/framework.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Unfortunately I don't have access to the core libraries source.